# Recover unsaved SQL query Scripts in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I know how to do this in SQL Server thanks to this clever bit of code

```
Use <database>
SELECT execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time], execsql.text AS [Script] 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC
```

> SOURCE:
>   [Recover unsaved SQL query scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034832/recover-unsaved-sql-query-scripts-sql-server)

Is there a way to do this in Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: `select * from v$sql`

Comment: `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 14`

Comment: The apparently you are missing the necessary privileges

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What privilege does this need to run?

Comment: It might also be worth checking the SQL Developer history. In my version 4.0.3.16: From the menu it is View --> SQL History or shortcut key F8

Comment: @IanCarpenter F8 works a charm! If you want to put this as an answer i will accept it :)

Comment: @Matt Nice one, glad it worked!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you have the privileges then:

```
SELECT * FROM v$sql
```

If not then press <kbd>F8</kbd> to bring up a list of previously ran queries.

Comment: this and all other solutions will provide only ```select``` statements that you ran. Any other commands ```alter```  for instance will not be found

Comment: @Kay, this is not correct. I am using SQL Developer version 21.4 and it does show all the commands executed including SELCT, ALTER, truncate, etc.

Answer (score 60):

[This](http://www.solveitproblems.net/2012/11/restore-unsaved-and-lost-plsql-code-in.html) has saved my butt several times.

> It is really a problem when you lose unsaved code. For about a
> month I have been working on a big procedure, and forgot to save the
> code in SVN. If you read this and remember have such unsaved code,
> commit it immediately! :) Because everything could happen with your
> test db. Ok. you're lucky if you were using Oracle SQL Developer,
> because this program has a great feature - it saves your code in its
> sql history inspite of eating a big party of your RAM. Open your file
> explorer and locate this folder:
>
> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\SqlHistory
>
> You'll find a lot of XML files, and if you're twice lucky, you'll find
> your lost code. It's wonderful. :) . If you're using another program,
> try to find a feature like this and maybe it helps you. My condolences
> if this post doesn't help you, in any case, try to find something good
> among the next: 1) write your code again, and it will be better than
> before as you did it once 2) commit your code, so you'll not face such
> problem in the future

Comment: This one saved me a lot of redo work today.  Thanks!

Comment: I think this history is the same history that is accessible via the GUI using the steps shown by Alberto Cerqueira above "View -> SQL History" (F8 keyboard shortcut).

Answer (score 20):

You can try too, so you can get the unsaved SQL.

**View > SQL History**, for example, look this picture:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is using SQLDeveloper's history, like in Matt's answer, but if you want to search through the history files for specific query fragments you remember, they are located as .xml files in `/home/username/.sqldeveloper/SqlHistory`. From there, enter:

`find -type f -mtime -1 -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l <text>`

(where `-mtime -1` means no sooner than one day ago).

Answer (score 3):

Through View> SQL History or by pressing F8 is a great way to do it, it lets you search for content or database connection, really a good implementation!

[SQL History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBXGB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the undo button, as shown in the image

[image: picture of undo and redo buttons]