# SSMS not responding without any error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

SSMS was working great until last night, and now it is not responding.  In windows task manager it shows it is running, but when I click on it, it is not responding.

I have many unsaved SQL Query windows, and I don't want to lose them.

I tried using `ALT + M` and see if activity monitor is open and I also tried suggestions from https://sqlblog.org/2009/06/25/what-to-do-when-management-studio-hangs.

Any response is highly appreciated. I am using `SQL server 2008 R2`

Comment: Repeated question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34505572/232589

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the ssms.
The script below provides a list of query's and the time of execution in the last 24 hours. So you can recover your query's.... but works only for executed scripts.

```
Use <database>
SELECT execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time], execsql.text AS [Script] FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC
```

Comment: dm_exec_query_stats contains plans that are in the cache. Once plan gets dropped from the cache it's gone and that depends on a lot of things, nothing to do with 24 hour limit.